# Bad deserialize with jackson

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-rest

I try to call an url who accept to list.

Data sent is

```
{"contactAvailableIdList":["1"],"contactIdList":["2","3"]}


Method on the server
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers/{lodgerId}/associate/dissociate/contact", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void associateLodgerAndContact(@PathVariable("lodgerId") Long lodgerId, @RequestBody @Valid final List<Long> contactIdList, @RequestBody @Valid final List<Long> contactAvailableIdList) {
    lodgerService.associateDissociateLodgerAndContact(lodgerId, contactIdList, contactAvailableIdList);
}
```

> "{"timestamp":1445958336633,"status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could
>   not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList
>   out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@5a1edae4; line: 1, column: 1]; nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT
>   token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5a1edae4; line: 1,
>   column: 1]","path":"/rest/lodgers/1/associate/dissociate/contact"}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not sure, if you can accept more requestbodies at once.

Standard way would be to have class

```
public class Contact{
  List<Long> contactIdList;
  List<Long> contactAvailableIdList;
}
```

And then accept it as

```
@RequestBody @Valid Contact contact
```

Also you are receiving array of string and you try to save them to array of Long. I am not sure either, if jackson tries implicitly to transform string elements of array to long in such case.

Comment: i changed to use a class, but the two list is null

Comment: Try List<String> instead of List<Long>

Comment: Jackson will do coercion from JSON Strings into integral numbers, if and as necessary, unless explicitly prevented by a config setting.